# Como dar output do indice do meu array em C?

Tags: c, array

Eu tenho um programa que irá verificar 9 números e dizer qual deles é o maior de todos, e para isto estou usando `vetor` já preenchido com valores, e estou usando um `for` para percorrer todo o `vetor` e procurar pelo maior. O problema é de que não estou conseguindo mostrar qual número do índice é o maior de todos.

**Meu código :**

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    int bolas[9] = {0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if(bolas[i] > bolas[i+1]) {
            printf("A bola %d é maior que todas as outras. ",bolas[i]);
        }
    }
```

Neste código, na parte do `printf` ele irá mostrar o tamanho do número, e não a sua posição no índice, eu preciso mostrar a posição e não o tamanho. Como posso fazer isto ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

se você está dando o `printf` dentro do `for`, ele está escrevendo várias vezes a mensagem. o que você precisa fazer, é, primeiro encontrar qual índice tem maior valor, e depois do `for` fazer a impressão (`printf`). Exemplo:

```
int bolas[9] = {0,0,0,0,20,0,0,0,0};
int maior = 0;
int i = 1;
for(i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    if(bolas[i] > bolas[maior]) {
        maior = i;
    }
}

printf("A bola %d é maior que todas as outras. ",bolas[maior]);
```

ou se quiser imprimir apenas o índice, e não o valor da bola:

```
printf("A bola %d é maior que todas as outras. ",maior);
```

Comment: Não funciona seu código, ele retorna a mesma coisa que o meu. Veja funcionando : http://ideone.com/UBrrhy.

Comment: Quer o índice? Manda escrever `maior`, pois esse é o índice do maior elemento do vetor

Comment: funciona!, `stdout: A bola 20 é maior que todas as outras.`

Comment: veja a alteração da resposta

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou mesmo, só uma correção, como o índice do array começa por 0, tem que colocar +1 no maior para ele dar o verdadeiro índice.

Comment: printf("Bola[%d] = %d eh a maior de todas", maior, bola[maior]) exibirá tanto o índice quanto o maior elemento, @Monteiro

Comment: @Monteiro índices começam em 0 ou 1? Na verdade, depende do conjunto semântico em que você está trabalhando, então para o conjunto semântico vetor c, está plenamente correta a solução dada

Comment: na verdade, o índice verdadeiro continuaria iniciando pelo 0 né...rs mas se pro usuário quer exibir inciando pelo 1, ok, só adicionar +1 ao índice

Comment: mas ta tranquilo, tinha uns 4 anos q não mexia com c rsrs

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, sou novo em C, então tudo bem, vou acreditar no que vocês dizem pois tem mais experiência do que eu. E funcionou certinho o código. + 1 e resposta certa.